# How to make calls to services dynamic depending on parameters passed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, nestjs, nest

I have a NestJS controller similar to the one below.So depending on the parameter passed in URL, I want to redirect to correct service.
The services will generally have the same functions in all with different functionality and have to be separate services.
There can be multiple services (maybe even more than 10) .There is going to be only 1 controller and I want the check to be in all functions/apis in the controller so if/else checks in all will be too cumbersome.So how can I centralize it so that I can check the id parameter and call the relevant service for all api requests?

```
class Controller {

 contructor(private readonly cnnService:CnnService,private readonly bbcService:BbcService)

 @Get(':id') 
 getNewsData() {
  // if id is cnn then 
  return this.cnnService.getNews()
  // else if id is bbc then
  return this.bbcService.getNews()

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should just be a simple `if`, right?

```js
class Controller {

 contructor(private readonly cnnService:CnnService,private readonly bbcService:BbcService)

 @Get(':id') 
 getNewsData(@Param() { id }: {id: string}) {
  if ( id === 'cnn') {
    return this.cnnService.getNews()
  } else if (id === 'bcc') {
    return this.bbcService.getNews()
  } else {
    throw new BadRequestException(`Unknown News outlet ${id}`);
  }
 }

}
```

---

If you have more than 4 or so services, I'd recommend registering each service as a [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers) like so:

```js
{
  provide: 'cnnService',
  useClass: CnnService
}
```

Adding this kind of custom provider for each news service you have in your `NewsModule` you can then inject the [`ModuleRef`](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref) class and do `return this.moduleRef.get(${id}Service).getNews()` in your controller method to change between which service is used, catching errors in a [filter](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters) as necessary.

Comment: Yes but there can be multiple services (maybe even more than 10) .There is going to be only 1 controller and I want the check to be in all functions/apis in the controller so if/else checks will be too cumbersome.So how can I centralize it  so that I can check the id parameter and call the relevant service for all api requests?

Comment: If there's that many services I would register them all via a similar naming scheme (`XService`) so they all have string tokens. Then you could use the `moduleRef` instead of injecting each service and do `this.moduleRef.get(${id}Service).getNews()` and catch an error if there is no service.

Comment: I really like this idea and did not know we could do this.So  I have added this code in the controller and it works fine if I directly call this.moduleRef.get(NewsService, { strict: false }).getNews()
Only issue is the name ${id}Service injection seems to be giving an error as it is not allowing me to do that.Any suggestion on that?
this.moduleRef.get(${id}Service, { strict: false }).getNews() gives an error

Comment: Added to my answer a few links and an example of a custom provider

Comment: Thanks I was able to implement the functionality with the custom provider